# Python regex for extracting digits from files in multiple formats

Tags: python, regex

I need help for a regex in python:

I have four files in a directory

- TOP GEAR 5X04.mkv
- TOP GEAR 13X02.avi
- TOP GEAR 9X12.mkv
- Game of thrones S02E03.mkv

and this is my regex in python:

```
/.*(S[0-9]{2})E[0-9]{2}.*|.*([0-9]+)X[0-9]+.*/
```

and it returns :

> Match 1
>
> 1. None
> 2. 5
>
> Match 2
>
> 1. None
> 2. 3
>
> Match 3
>
> 1. None
> 2. 9
>
> Match 4
>
> 1. S02
> 2. None

In Match 2.2, I have 3 and not 13. How can I get this latter please ? Any ideas ?

I've tried this but does not work at all :

```
/.*(S[0-9]{2})E[0-9]{2}.*|.*([0-9]{1,2})X[0-9]{1,2}.*/
```

[link Pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=.*(S%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D)E%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D.*%7C.*(%5B0-9%5D%2B)X%5B0-9%5D%2B.*&test_string=TOP%20GEAR%205X04.mkv%0ATOP%20GEAR%2013X02.avi%0ATOP%20GEAR%209X12.mkv%0AGame%20of%20thrones%20S02E03.mkv%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Thanks.

Comment: If you got it working, you could accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `.*` before the bit that should match the `13` lazy, by adding a `?`:

```
/.*(S[0-9]{2})E[0-9]{2}.*|.*?([0-9]{1,2})X[0-9]{1,2}.*/
```